# How to IE8 conditional comment

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, comments

Very Simple Question but I am finding it hard to get a good answer

If I wanted to remove certain divs when IE8 is used to view my webpage how would I do this ?

could you give me a coded example please.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that I read sth. that they stopped that with IE8. Their reason: "it is not necessary anymore"!

Comment: @ghommey: not so. In fact, MS's documentation on conditional comments includes examples specifically for targetting IE 8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

Comment: k sorry than it seem I mixed sth up...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) like this:

```
<!--[if !IE 8]>
    <div></div>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

the need of conditional comments in IE8 is very small.

Maybe you want to get in touch with "Reset Stylesheets"

In Addition to that question i want to provide some of my questions since they belong to same type of topic:

[Will Conditional Comments always be needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356665/will-conditional-comments-always-be-needed)

[Collection of Browser characteristics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346094/collection-of-browser-characteristics)