# Valid IE6 css hacks?

Tags: internet-explorer

Select all the CSS hack(s) that IE6 can understand for class red

```
<p class=”red”>text</p>

<!—[if IE 6]> .red{color:red}>![endif]-->
.red{_color:red}
.red{*color:red}
* html .red{color:red}
.red{color:red}
```

1. Line 1, 3
2. Line 2, 3
3. Line 2, 4
4. Line 1, 2, 4
5. All of the above

I encounter this question in a quiz. Don't have IE6 in my pc to experiment with but curious to know the answer.

My additional doubt, 
6. Which one is valid/suggested?
7. Is it still need to hack IE6 even after release of IE8? I don't expect a lengthy discussion on this. Just yes/no will do. My intention is to know how fellow coders feel about it. :-)

Comment: unfortunately supporting IE6 is something most web developers have to suffer with.  IE8 is much better than IE6, but many, many companies have yet to update (even to IE7)

Comment: IMHO: A **quiz** on CSS hacks seems a bit like quizzing for the proper way to spray paint a tomato plant.

Comment: ...it shouldn't ever be done, because it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, they all work. unless I'm confusing the * html for * > html, although I don't think they make a difference.

also, if they are asking for ONLY hacks, then obviously 5 wouldn't work because it's valid CSS, in which case **pick 4** because I think *color is iffy. I don't believe that's a real hack.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it still need to hack IE6 even
>   after release of IE8?

No...things get easier. But customer expections go higher and hgiher too. :-)

Check out some my questions related to that topic:

[Conditional Comments Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356665/will-conditional-comments-always-be-needed)

[Collect6ion of Browser Characteristics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346094/collection-of-browser-characteristics)